# lastModified to just time?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    var x = document.lastModified;
    document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = x;
```

Which returns something like: 10/14/2017 19:26:10.
How can I get it to return just the time portion of '19:26:10'?

Thank you.

Comment: How about splitting the string by space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(document.lastModified).toLocaleTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

---

```js
var x = document.lastModified;
document.getElementById("lastModified").innerHTML = prettyDate(x);
function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(time));
    var localeSpecificTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    return localeSpecificTime.replace(/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/](0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/](19|20)\d{2}$ /, ' ');
}
```

```html
<p id="lastModified"></p>
```